# Are 2 footers possible in phonegap, Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

are 2 footers possible in phonegap, jquery mobile. The second footer should be top of first one which is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Please share code part or effort done to accomplish this ..

Comment: but this is a suggestion . i am not working on a code. i am currently exploring phonegap .

Comment: Check this one http://jsfiddle.net/y4e6S/12/

Comment: Or try this navbar instead of above http://jsfiddle.net/y4e6S/13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `navbar` instead of two `footer` also two footer is not possible.

```
<div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
    <h1>Footer</h1>

</div>
```

Refer this [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y4e6S/13/)